# How to check a greater than check in reg expression?

Tags: python, regex, robotframework

How to use a `greater than` check in robot framework reg expression?

```
 show_output    name=${item_name}    action=get    output_regexp=<ip>10.10.10.1</ip>, <time> >60 </time>
```

I want to ensure that the value of `<time>` is more than 60 secs. How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are for finding patterns, not performing arithmetic. You simply can't do what you want with regular expressions. At least, not without a really complicated expression that matches 61, 62, 63, etc or any number that is a 7 followed by one or more digits, or any group of three or more digits where the third-from-the-last digit is at least 1, and there aren't any decimal points or a leading negative sign, ...

It's easier to pull the number out and do the logical test on a separate line.